# Mailchimp clicks not showing up in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, mailchimp

I sent a mailchimp campaign today and it shows 53 clicks. The clicks lead to a webinar sign up page on our website.

When I look at Google analytics, I see only 16 sessions. I would have expected. at least 53 sessions - probably more....

Where did all the clickers go? Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Antony

Comment: Is it not possible that a single session contains multiple clicks?

Comment: 16 sessions in total for that page or 16 sessions attributed to Mailchimp ? If the latter, do you see a spike in another channel for that page (in that case the problem would be with attribution - maybe campaign parameter get lost along the way, or something causes the session to be reattributed).

Comment: @Matt Not according to the way google looks at sessions: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

Comment: @EikePierstorff it is 16 sessions in total!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use UTM tracking? this might help and the it should show up under Acquisition=>All traffic=>source/medium.